# Exporting Visual Studio 2010 .rdlc report to PDF renders the font too large

Tags: report-viewer2010, export-to-pdf

I have a report that renders perfectly fine on screen, but when I export it to PDF one section is rendering the font HUGE, making it unreadable. The part that is getting rendered so big is a field I have set up to store rich text, which then gets converting to html. I did not roll this solution myself, but from what I understand it runs an rtftohtml method to render to the screen, and then it runs through the same method again to re-render it to a PDF, which is why I am confused. The first rendering (to the screen) looks perfect, and then the second rendering (to pdf) looks like garbage. I have seen a few threads on this topic in some other forums but not a single one has a response, so I am hoping the SO community has a possible work around or fix for this!

Comment: Is the font size explicitly set in the report? If not, that would be my first port of call.

Comment: Yes, in the rdlc file it is set to 8 point arial. When I inspect the html when it is rendered to the screen the font is also set the 8 pt in the css. So it all acts normal, but as soon as I try to throw it in a pdf the font size just to like 120